# Apply a function row by row using other dataframes' rows as list inputs in python

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda, apply

I'm trying to apply a function row-by-row which takes 5 inputs, 3 of which are lists. I want these lists to come from each row of 3 correspondings dataframes.

I've tried using 'apply' and 'lambda' as follows:

```
sol['tf_dd']=sol.apply(lambda tsol, rfsol, rbsol: 
                           taurho_difdif(xy=xy,
                                         l=l,
                                         t=tsol,
                                         rf=rfsol,
                                         rb=rbsol),
                           axis=1)
```

However I get the error `<lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'rfsol' and 'rbsol'`

The DataFrame `sol` and the DataFrames `tsol`, `rfsol` and `rbsol` all have the same length. For each row, I want the entire row from `tsol`, `rfsol` and `rbsol` to be input as three lists.

Here is much simplified example (first with single lists, which I then want to replicate row by row with dataframes):

The output with single lists is a single value (120). With dataframes as inputs I want an output dataframe of length 10 where all values are 120.

```
t=[1,2,3,4,5]
rf=[6,7,8,9,10]
rb=[11,12,13,14,15]

def simple_func(t, rf, rb):
    x=sum(t)
    y=sum(rf)
    z=sum(rb)

    return x+y+z

out=simple_func(t,rf,rb)

# dataframe rows as lists
tsol=pd.DataFrame((t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t))
rfsol=pd.DataFrame((rf,rf,rf,rf,rf,rf,rf,rf,rf,rf))
rbsol=pd.DataFrame((rb,rb,rb,rb,rb,rb,rb,rb,rb,rb))


out2 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(tsol)), columns=['output'])
out2['output'] = out2.apply(lambda tsol, rfsol, rbsol:
                            simple_func(t=tsol.tolist(),
                                        rf=rfsol.tolist(),
                                        rb=rbsol.tolist()),
                            axis=1)
```

Comment: are you just trying to merge dataframes ? Or are you trying to combine the columns of 3 dataframes into a single column?

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would be useful here - to see an example of the input, and desired outputs

Comment: I'm trying to use 3 dataframes as 3 inputs to create another dataframe, where each row of the three input dataframes is a list.

Comment: I am struggling to visualise this - sorry - maybe it is just me....

Comment: I've added a simple (hopefully reproducible) example

Comment: your `simple_func()` is returning a single value - was that the intention ?

Comment: And for your reproducible example - what did you want the output to look like ? (hint: use a `random.seed(10)` to allow for reproducibility.)

Comment: In the example with the dataframes as inputs, the output dataframe will have length 10 and one column 'output'. The the value in the i-th row of 'out2' will be equal to the sum of values in the i-th row of tsol + the sum of values in the i-th row of rfsol + the sum of values in the i-th row of rbsol.

Comment: I've modified the example to make it more reproducible, hope that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use "name" field in Series Type to get index value, and then get the same index for the other DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def postional_sum(inot, df1, df2, df3):
    """
        Get input index and gather the same position for the other DataFrame collection
    """

    position = inot.name

    x = df1.iloc[position].sum()
    y = df2.iloc[position].sum()
    z = df3.iloc[position].sum()
    return x + y + z


# dataframe rows as lists
tsol = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5), columns=range(5))
rfsol = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5), columns=range(5))
rbsol = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5), columns=range(5))

out2 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(tsol)), columns=["output"])

out2["output"] = out2.apply(lambda x: postional_sum(x, tsol, rfsol, rbsol), axis=1)

out2
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much, this sorted it!

Answer (score 0):

When you run `df.apply()` with `axis=1`, it does not pass on the columns as individual arguments to the function, but as a Series object, as explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/apply-function-to-every-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe/). The correct way to do this would be

```
out2['output'] = out2.apply(lambda row:
                            simple_func(t=row["tsol"],
                                        rf=row["rfsol"],
                                        rb=row["rbsol"]),
                            axis=1)
```

Comment: tsol, rfsol and rbsol are not columns of out2, i got that error : 

KeyError: 'tsol'

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question and assumed you were trying to run a function with every column in the data. I didn't realize `tsol`, `rfsol`, and `rbsol` were preexisting DataFrames. However, `df.apply()` should be used when you want to do calculations with information already stored in the DataFrame, but as the information is in seperate DataFrames, you should use the solution by @ScottC.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the simple function using this:

```
out2["output"] = tsol.sum(axis=1) + rfsol.sum(axis=1) + rbsol.sum(axis=1)
```

**Here is the complete code:**

```
t=[1,2,3,4,5]
rf=[6,7,8,9,10]
rb=[11,12,13,14,15]

# dataframe rows as lists
tsol=pd.DataFrame((t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t))
rfsol=pd.DataFrame((rf,rf,rf,rf,rf,rf,rf,rf,rf,rf))
rbsol=pd.DataFrame((rb,rb,rb,rb,rb,rb,rb,rb,rb,rb))

out2 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(tsol)), columns=["output"])
out2["output"] = tsol.sum(axis=1) + rfsol.sum(axis=1) + rbsol.sum(axis=1)

print(out2)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   output
0     120
1     120
2     120
3     120
4     120
5     120
6     120
7     120
8     120
9     120
```

Comment: Thank you, but this function was just to simplify the concept. In reality I have much more complex functions which however take the same type of input and return the same type of output. AntonioRB's solution worked great